# What is the best solution to this? (Any Language)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, fizzbuzz

Here is a question. Can someone figure out the answer?

Maximum two "if" tests are allowed!

```
Given numbers from 1 to 100
If this number is divisble by 21 print "foobar"
If this number is divisble by 7 print "bar"
If this number is divisble by 3 print "foo"
If none of the above, print the number
```

Only one number should be printed. For example, number 21 should only print "foobar", not all "foobar", "bar", "foo".

Can be done in any language.

Many thanks.

Comment: Further reading: Search for FizzBuzz.

Comment: Where does the question come from? Is it an interview question? Homework?

Comment: Is the restriction only on `if`'s, or on all branching flow control (like `switch/case`) or the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @George Duckett: given the question is language-agnostic, I think you need to restrict any kind of branching/conditional control flow. Otherwise I can just invent a language "French C++", in which I can use the keyword `si` as many times as I like because it's not `if` ;-) Then you can have an argument about what a "branch" really is, comparing the logical structure of the code, the actual opcodes emitted by a given compiler, etc, etc. It's an artificial restriction invented by an interviewer in order to provoke a particular answer, which you gave.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Exactly my point :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that realising of the 4 ifs in your question, we can infer the top and bottom ones based on the middle 2.

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    string numberstr = i.ToString();
    if(i % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("foo");
        numberstr = "";
    }
    if(i % 7 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("bar");
        numberstr = "";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(numberstr);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ohai, FizzBuzz.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  for(int i=1; i <= 100; ++i){
    bool foo = !(i % 3), bar = !(i % 7);
    bool num = !(foo || bar);
    foo && std::cout << "foo";
    bar && std::cout << "bar";
    num && std::cout << i;
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/9RInp)

Comment: Oooh, nice one, another with zero if statements. Although it's borderline. No doubt you could do something similar with `while (foo) {cout << "foo"; break;}` or a ternary :-) They're also technically not `if` statements.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that whoever invented the question had in mind a for loop containing two "ifs". So, "for" loops *definitely* don't count as "ifs", and we can have `for(int tmp = i; tmp % 3 == 0; ++tmp) std::cout << "foo";`. Assuming we think the interviewer will enjoy that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

A zero if using linq (but cheating really by using the conditional operator).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                        let foopart = i % 3 == 0 ? "foo" : ""
                        let barpart = i % 7 == 0 ? "bar" : ""
                        let numberpart = i % 3 != 0 && i % 7 != 0 ? i.ToString() : ""
                        select foopart + barpart + numberpart;

            foreach (var line in lines)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can do this with *zero* `if` statements:

```
array[1..100] = {"1", "2", "foo", "4", "5", "6", "bar", ... "bar", "foo", "100"}
for i = 1 to 100:
    print array[i]
```

I'll leave it up to you to fill in the `...` bit and convert it to a real language. I'd do it myself but I doubt the usefulness of such a task :-)

Or, perhaps even better:

```
print "1\n2\nfoo\n4\n...97\nbar\nfoo\n100"
```

Comment: Now this is called cheating ;)

Comment: To which my response would be "Kobayashi Maru" :-)

Comment: In Haskell, you wouldn't need to fill in the `...`, nor convert it to a real language. The compiler would devise a language for you and then compile it using that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are 3 conditions, but no IF :) C#

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(n =>
            n % 21 == 0 ? "foobar" :
            n % 7 == 0 ? "bar" :
            n % 3 == 0 ? "foo" : n.ToString());
foreach(var n in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in C

```
char* x = "\n"; 
int i;
for(i=1;i<=75;i++)
{   
    int y = ((i%5 == 0) && printf("%s","Foo")); 
    y=y+((i%7 == 0) && printf("%s","Bar"));
    ((!y==1) && printf("%d",i));
    printf("%s",x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

save the result in a string.

Example:

String str = number.toString();

```
if(number % 7 == 0) {
   str = "FOO";
}

if(number % 5 == 0) {
   str = i % 7 == 0 ? str + "BAR" : "BAR";
}

return str;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pseudcode:
if (num/3)
{
    print foo
}
elseif (num/7)
{
    print bar
}
else
{
        print num
}
```

basically foobar will get concatenated when a number divisible by 21 is encountered.

Comment: Doesn't print `foobar` if the number is divisible by 21.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
        int mul3  = (i /3)*3;
        int mul7 = (i /7) * 7;
        String fooOrBar = (mul3 == i && mul7 == i) ? "foobar" :(mul3 == i) ? "foo" : (mul7 == i) ? "bar" : "";
        System.out.println(fooOrBar);

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to meet the maximum two if tests requirement in the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you please brief what that mean by maximum two? I will edit in my code

Comment: The question states - Maximum two "if" tests are allowed! You have three if tests in your answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I did the change .

Comment: That's obeying the letter of the law rather than its spirit as ? : is basically an if else test and you still have 3 of those.